# Should session ID be sent to GA4 as a User Property in the configuration tag?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, sessionid

I currently have a user-defined variable in GTM that gets the GA Session ID from the cookies.  I am inclined to add it as a user property to the GA4 Page View/Configuration tag and then register it as a user-scoped dimension in GA4 (since session-scope doesn't exist yet).  My question is, what impact will treating session ID as a user property and dimension have on the data collection?

I should add, I am doing this in order to have the Session ID accessible by API for use with the Measurement Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that the Session ID is send as an event parameter in the MP.  Therefore, seems pretty clear that it should be event-scoped and passed with an event tag!

Answer (score 0):

You may capture Session ID and Session Number by defining the required custom dimension in your GA4 Admin section. https://help.channelmix.com/hc/en-us/articles/19904317846035

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34910777)